# how to skip two lines and delete two lines till the end of file in vim?

Tags: linux, vim, awk, sed, vi

I want to skip two lines and delete two lines till the end of file

if my file contains

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
777
888
999
1010
1111
```

I want to modify it to look like

```
111
222
555
666
999
1010
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
awk 'NR%4==1 || NR%4==2' file
111
222
555
666
999
1010
```

`NR%4==1` prints line 1,5,9 etc
`NR%4==2` prints line 2,6,10 etc
So it gives line 1,2 5,6 9,19 etc

---

Other version:

```
awk 'NR%4~/^[12]$/' #JS웃
awk '(NR-1)%4<2'    #Ed Morton
```

Comment: **Code golf:** `awk 'NR%4~/^[12]$/' file`?

Comment: awk '(NR-1)%4<2' file. Fore :-)!

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n 'p;n;p;n;n' inputfile
```

For your given input, it'd produce:

```
111
222
555
666
999
1010
```

Using GNU sed:

```
sed -n '1~4p;2~4p' inputfile
```

For fun, one could also use `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if grep($_==$.%4,(1,2))' inputfile
```

Comment: I would use `perl` `:P` +1

Comment: @JS웃 The perl variant is deliberately written in a not-so-clean manner.

Comment: I know, cleaner solution would look quite similar to `awk` - `perl -ne 'print if $.%4==1||$.%4==2' inputFile`

Comment: @JS웃 But then I could have been accused of plagiarism `:P`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'n;n;$!N;d' file
```

Answer (score 0):

A vim only solution:

```
:%norm Jj2dd Aaaaa
```

then

```
:%s/aaaa /\r/g
```

You need to split the first line manually(have n), rest everything is in place.